# Using Postgres JSONB query with Spring Data and bind parameter fails with InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I am currently looking for a solution for the exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist;
```

My current `@Query` annotation is:

```
@Query(
    nativeQuery = true, 
    value = "SELECT * FROM thgcop_order_placement WHERE \"order_info\" @> '{\"parentOrderNumber\":\" :param \"}'")
```

I guess the `position [1] did not exist` comes from it being in double quotes plus double quote plus single quote.

How can I make this work?

The query is using Postgres `JSONB` datatype. The column definition is `ORDER_INFO JSONB`

The following native query works just fine in the Postgres client:

```
SELECT * FROM thgcop_order_placement
WHERE "order_info" @> '{"parentOrderNumber":"ORD123"}'
```

Comment: Does Postgres support bind variables in that way? I'd think that the quotes around `:param` are superfluous.

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace?

Comment: @JensSchauder, at 1-point if we think about a pure SQL query which i have mentioned into "Update" block. that's perfectly right. if i try to remove the quotes then Postgres gives an error. that's why my strong believe it it should be required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None of the above worked for me except the below,

**Service Layer code :-**

```
OrderInfo orderInfo = new OrderInfo();
orderInfo.setParentOrderNumber("ORD123");
....
String param = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderInfo);
List<Order> list = jpaRepository.getByParentOrderNumber(param);
```

**JpaRepository.java code :-**

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from thgcop_order_placement where order_info @> CAST(:condition as jsonb)")
List<Order> getByParentOrderNumber(@Param("condition") String parentOrderNumber);
```

This is how I achieve the result. I hope this will be very helpful for all *enthusiastic*!!

> Thank you all for your help !!!

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Make it work with Bind Parameter and plain JDBC first. Then move on to Spring Data, possibly falling back on a custom implementation.

You are facing problems on many levels here.

1. Let's start with ignoring Spring Data for now.
   The statement you showed is very dissimilar from the one you try to construct with Spring Data because it doesn't contain a bind variable.
   So instead of

   ```
   SELECT * FROM thgcop_order_placement WHERE "order_info" @> '{"parentOrderNumber":"ORD123"}'
   ```

   We should compare it to

   ```
   SELECT * FROM thgcop_order_placement WHERE "order_info" @> '{"parentOrderNumber": ? }'
   ```

   Note that we are losing the quotes since they denote a literal String but we aren't providing a literal String but a bind parameter.
2. I haven't found any indication that you can use bind parameters in parts of JSON expressions. So instead of the statement above we would need to use:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM thgcop_order_placement WHERE "order_info" @> ?
   ```

   Of course, the bind parameter should then contain the complete JSON expression
3. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work either because now Postgres considers the bind parameter a `VARCHAR` instead of a JSON expression. See https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/processing-json/. I think the correct version should be

   ```
   SELECT * FROM thgcop_order_placement WHERE "order_info" @> ?::json
   ```

   But I couldn't get this to work either.
4. In any case, you are left to transform your parameter to the JSON structure. 
   Normally I'd suggest using a SpEL expression for this. But it won't work because Spring Data chokes on the curly braces needed in the SpEL expression and considers them the end of the SpEL expression.
5. If you get something like this to work with a simple JDBC connection or `JdbcTemplate` you can start to think about `@Query` annotations.

   ```
   @Query(
       value= "SELECT * FROM thgcop_order_placement WHERE \"order_info @> :name::json",
       nativeQuery = true)
   ```

This might trigger more problems since Spring Data will either consider `::json` part of the parameter name. If this is the case you'll have to fall back on custom implementations.

[I ran a couple of experiments, which you can look at and play with here.](https://github.com/schauder/stackoverflow-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/de/schauderhaft/stackoverflow/postgresjsonb/PostgresjsonbTest.java)

Comment: I will try it out & will let you know .

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind parameters as following

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM thgcop_order_placement"
  + " WHERE \"order_info\" @> '{\"parentOrderNumber\":\" ?1 \"}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at the same problem for a while as well. It seems that springboot messes up while parsing the query present in string format. However this is the solution that I found, which will work directly as a native query in the repository:

- Since `order_info` is of the type `jsonb`, the value being searched can be casted as a jsonb value.
- Value to be searched: `{"parentOrderNumber":"ORD123"}`
- Let's escape the whole string to be parsed by java.
- `String searchString = "{\"parentOrderNumber\":\"ORD123\"}"`
- Now, let's type the postgres query in a manner that spring will understand.

```
@Query(
value = "SELECT * from thgcop_order_placement where ((?1\\:\\:jsonb) <@ (order_info\\:\\:jsonb))",
nativeQuery=true
)
List<Order> getByParentOrderNumber(String searchString);
```

Where,

- Spring will replace `?1` with the value of `searchString`, as defined above.
- `::` is the typecast operator using which, we are explicitly typecasting the passed parameter (`searchString`) into `jsonb`. Therefore the value `{\"parentOrderNumber\":\"ORD123\"}` is converted into `jsonb` before an attempt is made for a search.
- Also the values of column `order_info` is explicitly typecasted into `jsonb`.
- Now, when both items (value to be searched and the column) are the same data type, we can use the `<@` operator to check if the search string is contained in the column values.

At the service level we just have to do this:

```
String orderNumber = "-- some order value e.g. ORD123 --"
String searchString = "{\"parentOrderNumber\":\"" + orderNumber + "\"}"
List<Order> list = jpaRepository.getByParentOrderNumber(searchString);
```

More details on Postgres JSON operators can be found in the official documentation HERE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html