# Spring-Data-JPA native query on jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

Given the following JSON which is stored as jsonb in a postgres table:

```
{
    "object" : {
        "array" [
            {
                "uuid" : "34ad3558-a3e7-43d0-826f-afddce255b20"
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

I have a working query to search if a `field` value is present within the JSON document:

```
select * from my_table 
where my_json@>'{"object": {"array" : [{"field": "34ad3558-a3e7-43d0- 
826f-afddce255b20"}]}}';
```

However when I try to replicate this query in Spring-Data-JPA using a native query on a JPARepository I keep getting the following exception:

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist`

I initally tried:

```
@Query(value = "Select * From my_table"
     + "and my_json@>'{\"object\": {\"array\" : [{\"uuid\": \"?1\"}]}}'",
    nativeQuery = true)
Set<MyEntity> myQuery(UUID uuid);
```

Following this I tried binding the parameter with `@Param` :

```
@Query(value = "Select * From my_table"
     + "and my_json@>'{\"object\"\\: {\"array\" \\: [{\"uuid\"\\: \":uuid\"}]}}'",
    nativeQuery = true)
Set<MyEntity> myQuery(@Param("uuid") UUID uuid);
```

After that I tried converting the UUID to a String:

```
@Query(value = "Select * From my_table"
     + "and my_json@>'{\"object\"\\: {\"array\" \\: [{\"uuid\"\\: \":uuid\"}]}}'",
    nativeQuery = true)
Set<MyEntity> myQuery(@Param("uuid") String uuid);
```

Still nothing works. The JPA entity looks like this :

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column("my_json")
    private MyJson myJson
}
```

Other queries that invole the entity work fine with the jsonb field binding to MyJson entity. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I found a work around solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47898476/9080066. I am still open to other solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the value in your native query.

```
cast(:uuid as UUID)
```

So your query becomes.

```
@Query(value = "Select * From my_table"
 + "and my_json@>'{\"object\"\\: {\"array\" \\: [{\"uuid\"\\: cast(:uuid as UUID)}]}}'",
nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: I will try this, but if this is the case why did it not work as a string?