# Using Postgres JSON function in Hibernate with injection

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate + SpringBoot and have a @Query() with nativeQuery=true where I am attempting to use a Postgres jsonb function to find a row where a JSON list has an entry with a specific field value, where banana_id is a parameter:

```
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(CAST(foo.things as jsonb), '$[*] ? (@.id == :banana_id)')
```

but no matter what I try, the query fails. According to this post [Using Postgres JSONB query with Spring Data and bind parameter fails with InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806851/using-postgres-jsonb-query-with-spring-data-and-bind-parameter-fails-with-invali) it's impossible to inject into a json path query, so that's why :banana_id doesn't work, but I can't figure out how to reframe this without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up injecting the whole query as a string and casting it to jsonpath, with this:

```
jsonb_path_exists(CAST(foo.things as jsonb), CAST(:query_str as jsonpath))
```